# Prove that $u_n = \ln\left(\frac{n^{n+\frac 12}}{n!e^n}\right)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let for $n>1$ : $$u_n = \ln\left(\frac{n^{n+\frac 12}}{n!e^n}\right)$$

I've proved that :

$$u_{n+1} - u_n = 2\int_0^{\frac 12} \frac{x^2 dx}{(n+\frac 12)^2-x^2}$$

and thus

$$0\leq u_{n+1}-u_n \leq \frac 14 \left(\frac 1n - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

I'm asked to deduce from that that $(u_n)$ converges and I don't see how. The convergence of $u_{n+1}-u_n$ doesn't help if I'm not mistaken...

Thanks !

(side note : the real question was to show $u_{n+1}-u_n \leq \frac{1}{12}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$ but I think this is a mistake in the question as $\frac 14$ seems more logical to me.)

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n(n+1)}<\infty.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I see it now thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series $ \sum (u_{n+1} - u_n)$ and the sequence ($u_n$) have the same bevahior. Hence if you prove that the series $ \sum (u_{n+1} - u_n)$ converges then it also means that  ($u_n$) converges.

With your inequality, you can show that $u_{n+1} - u_n=O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ which implies that the series $ \sum (u_{n+1} - u_n)$ is convergent.

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat little trick.

Comment: You can think of it like if $u_{n+1} - u_n$ converges quickly enough to $0$ then $u_n$ converges